# UIBezierPath subpaths which forms closed path cannot be represented in SVG

Tags: ios, svg, uiwebview, uibezierpath

i need to convert UIBezierPath to SVG.
my UIBezierPath internally has collection cubic bezier paths as subpaths.
these subpaths when taken together forms a closed path, meaning, the last cubic-bezier's endpoint is same as first cubic-bezier's startpoint.

when i draw this path on a CAShapeLayer with some fill color, the overall path is filled with given color correctly.

now, I need to simulate the same behavior in SVG ( which is loaded inside a webview ), problem is the sub-paths are independent in svg and i can't combine them (group them) into a single path, so we lose the contextual information that this collection of paths are closed and hence fail to fill.

i tried to put these svg cubic-beizer path inside g element , that didnt work either. like below

```
<g>
<path  d="M1013.3,1228.7 C1007.1,1238.4 991.4,1242.6 984.2,1242.6" />
<path  d="M984.2,1233.6 C995.1,1237.3 1008.3,1231.7 1013.2,1231.7" />
<path  d="M1013.2,1221.3 C1018.0,1210.9 1013.8,1197.1 1004.0,1197.1" />
</g>
```

how do i solve this problem ? any inputs are appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can't you just create a single path that has the contents of all the d attributes concatenated together?

Comment: Yes, i figured out after posting the question that we can concatenate the subpaths to the main paths, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand, but you can use as many beziers path as you want in the same curve. Here is a way: http://jsfiddle.net/74os2um3/

Just put it in one `<path>` and add a `Z` to close it.

```
<path  d="M1013.3,1228.7 C1007.1,1238.4 991.4,1242.6 984.2,1242.6 L984.2,1233.6 C995.1,1237.3 1008.3,1231.7 1013.2,1231.7 L1013.2,1221.3 C1018.0,1210.9 1013.8,1197.1 1004.0,1197.1 Z" />
```

Comment: Yes, we could do that ! my bad, i should have give it more thought on the Path details. Thanks for providing details.